# How to indent a block of code in Pharo / Squeak?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, smalltalk, indentation, pharo, squeak

With a selected a block of code, I try to indent it by pressing TAB.

I would expect the code to be *indented*.

Instead, the selected text is **deleted** and **replaced** by a TAB.

How come? Is there any other **shortcut** for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a newcomer to Pharo/Squeak you might expect to indent a block of code by pressing TAB/SHIFT-TAB.

As it turns out, this is not the way it works as of **Pharo 1.4** / **Squeak 4.3** (however this **might change in the future**, see comment below).

The correct **shortcuts** for indenting-**Right** / indenting-**Left** are:

```
                 Indent (right)        Outdent (left)
    Win/Linux:    Ctl + Alt + R         Ctl + Alt + L 
    Mac:          Cmd + Shift + R       Cmd + Shift + L
```

So: it's R/L for right/left.

Comment: As a side note: Shortcut keys are about to change (sooner than later hopefully) and become more customizable (they already are more customizable than they used to be). There's currently an interesting discussion on the mailing list about vim like shortcuts: http://forum.world.st/Re-Vim-Keys-td4657381.html

Comment: @MaxLeske: Looks like that never happened... but please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, the shortcut named above doesn't work in the latest Pharo and Seaside images.

Comment: You're right. Interestingly, the same thing is being discussed on the mailing list again right now. Never ending story... Actually, the short cuts still work in the system browser (at least for me) but *not* in the playground (a.k.a. workspace) and Spotter (I don't know what the shortcuts are there). One goal of the current development is to unify keybindings.